# How do I send an array to a function?

Tags: javascript

i work with javascript.

i create a new array:

```
var d = new Array(4);
d[0] = "0";
d[1] = "1";
d[2] = "2";
d[3] = "3";
```

how could i send the 'd' Array to function?

```
cc( 'the d array' );

function cc( array ) {
///
}
```

Comment: `cc(d)`? Am I missing something?

Comment: @AdrianWragg i dont know, its not work for me. i will try it again

Comment: What is happening when you call `cc(d)`? Can you please be more specific than *it's not working*?

Comment: @ldoroni You need to supply more code. There is literally nothing you've given here to not work.

Answer (score 2):

Define your array as:

```
var d = ["0","1","2", "3"];
```

Define the function and call it like this:

```
function cc(my_array) {
    console.log(my_array[0]);
}

cc(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var d = [0,1,2,3];

function cc(arr) {
    return arr[0];
}

cc(d);
```

Just pass the array into the function call.

Comment: I'd upvote this, but I sense OP hasn't told us everything yet.

Comment: You may be right @kojiro, however the question did make sense and was clear enough to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample:

```
    function cc( array ) {
        <!-- your code //-->
        array[0]="TEST0";
    }

    var d = new Array(4);
    d[0] = "0";
    d[1] = "1";
    d[2] = "2";
    d[3] = "3";

    cc( d );
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm I don't know if I understand your question correctly but if I do:

```
function cc(array) {
    //...your stuff here
}

var d = ["apples", "bananas", "other fruit"];
//Call the function
cc(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function print_array(arr)
 {
   alert(arr);
 }

 var my_array = new Array();
 my_array[0] = "a";
 my_array[1] = "b";
 my_array[2] = "c";

print_array(my_array);
```